chrome拡張機能がうまく動作しない　やりたいことはjavascriptでページ内に記載してあるパスを取得し、整形して、ページ内に要素を追加する
ページ内のパスを手動で選択コピーしないといけないため、コピーしやすくしたいと思い、chrome拡張機能を作っています。
対象ページのコンソールでcontent.jsファイル内をすべてコピーして実行すると、意図したとおりに動作します。chrome拡張機能で、ページを読み込んだ際にcontent.jsが実行されるようにしたいです。
下の赤の完全パスを取得して、整形したのち上に表示するような形にしています。この薄い灰色の要素がページ内で繰り返されています。

フォルダ内の階層はこのようになっています

manifest.json これの設定がうまくできていないのだと思っています
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Copy Path Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Add copy path functionality to GitHub diff pages.",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "clipboardWrite"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://<myCompanyDomain>:8080/tfs/<hoge>/<hoge1>/<hoge2>/<hoge3>*"
      ],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "/icons/icon.jpg",
    "48": "/icons/icon.jpg",
    "128": "/icons/icon.jpg"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
          "content.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

content.js　こちらものせておきます
function getDiffContent() {
  // Find all <code> elements with class 'hljs'
  const codeElements = document.querySelectorAll('.hljs');
  
  // Array to hold the content of each <code> element
  const codeContents = [];
  
  // Loop through each <code> element and get its content
  codeElements.forEach(code => {
    codeContents.push(code.innerText);
  });
  
  // Return the array of code contents
  return codeContents;
}

function extractPaths(diffContents) {
  // Array to hold the extracted paths
  const paths = [];
  
  diffContents.forEach(diff => {
    const pathMatch = diff.match(/\+\+\+ b\/(.+)/);
    if (pathMatch) {
      const fullPath = pathMatch[1];
      const themePathMatch = fullPath.match(/\/Theme\/Responsive\/.*/);
      if (themePathMatch) {
        paths.push(themePathMatch[0]);
      }
    }
  });
  
  return paths.length > 0 ? paths : ["パスが見つかりませんでした。"];
}

function addPathsAfterPreElements() {
  // Get the diff content from the page
  const diffContents = getDiffContent();
  
  // Extract the paths from the diff contents
  const extractedPaths = extractPaths(diffContents);
  
  // Get all <pre> elements with class 'hljs'
  const preElements = document.querySelectorAll('pre.hljs');
  
  // Loop through each <pre> element and add a <p> tag with the extracted path and a copy button after each <pre>
  preElements.forEach((pre, index) => {
    const path = extractedPaths[index] || "パスが見つかりませんでした。";
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    p.textContent = path;
    
    // https通信だとうまくいかないため、コメントアウトしている
    // TODO　回避策を見つける
    // Create a span for better styling
    // const span = document.createElement('span');
    // span.textContent = ' (クリックしてコピー)';
    // span.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    // span.style.color = 'blue';
    // span.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //   copyToClipboard(path);
    // });
    
    // p.appendChild(span);
    
    const container = document.createElement('div');
    container.appendChild(p);
    
    // Insert the container (p + button) after the <pre> element
    pre.parentNode.insertBefore(container, pre.nextSibling);
  });
}

function copyToClipboard(text) {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then(() => {
    alert('クリップボードにパスがコピーされました: ' + text);
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error('クリップボードにパスのコピーが失敗しました:', err);
    alert('クリップボードにパスのコピーが失敗しました');
  });

  // Select the text in the path element
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  const range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(document.getElementById('path-element-id')); // Replace 'path-element-id' with the actual ID or element selector of your path element
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
}


// Run the function to add paths after <pre> elements
addPathsAfterPreElements();


何卒宜しくお願い致します。
